# Como salvar uma hash em um arquivo?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Código:

```
h = {}
arquivo = open("Tabela nome-idade.txt")
r = True
while r:
    nome = str(input("Nome: "))
    if nome == '':
        r = False
        print(h)
        break
    idade = str(input("Idade: "))
    h[nome] = idade
```

Minha dúvida é que tentei usar o

```
'arquivo.write(h)'
```

e não funcionou pois ele pede estritamente por strings, então gostaria de saber o que posso usar para que seja possível salvar as hashs em um arquivo.

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode salvar a dict(hash) em um arquivo, porque ela é uma estrutura de dados em memória.
Você precisa de uma maneira de representar essa estrutura de dados de modo que dê pra escrevê-la em disco, isso se chama serialização.

Há várias formas de serializar objetos em python, vou citar duas delas aqui.

---

#### Pickle

O python dispõe de uma biblioteca específica para serialização de objetos, chamada [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pickle.html), que você pode usar para atingir seu objetivo.

O uso mais básico seria dessa forma:

```
import pickle

h = {}
arquivo = open("Tabela nome-idade.pkl", "wb")
r = True
while r:
    nome = str(input("Nome: "))
    if nome == '':
        r = False
        print(h)
        break
    idade = str(input("Idade: "))
    h[nome] = idade

pickle.dump(h, arquivo)
arquivo.close()
```

E para recuperar o objeto do arquivo:

```
import pickle

arquivo = open("Tabela nome-idade.pkl", "rb")
h = pickle.load(arquivo)
arquivo.close()
```

#### JSON

No caso específico de uma dict, você poderia transformá-la para uma string no formato JSON, e salvar a string num arquivo, desde que a dict contenha apenas outras dicts, listas ou strings.

Útil caso você queira serializar objetos que devem ser lidos em programas escritos em outras linguagens, como javascript, pois todas elas terão suporte a serialização/deserialização em JSON.

Para serializar como JSON:

```
import json

h = {'a': 1, 'b': [2,3,4]}
j = json.dumps(h)
with open('arquivo.txt', 'w') as arquivo:
   arquivo.write(j)
```

E para deserializar:

```
import json

with open('arquivo.txt', 'r') as arquivo:
   j = arquivo.read()
   h = json.loads(j)  # Objeto recuperado
```